# SpriteKit iPhone/iPad different resolution, need same physics

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

As I am porting an iPhone app that uses SpriteKit to iPad, I have been able to scale all the screen elements and font sizes using the height ratio of the iPhone 5 to iPad screen.

Everything looks proportional, except for the physics since there is more area.

So the question is, how do I scale the physics along with the screen using that height ratio?

Perhaps changing density or mass of all the nodes? How would I do it, mathematically using the ratio so that it is perfect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can configure the `SKPhysicsWorld` object attached to the `SKScene`.
It changes:

- The *gravity* property that applies an acceleration to volume-based bodies in the simulation.
- The *speed* property determines the rate at which the simulation runs.

You can set those **properties** to values that seems good to you on an iPad. Changing the *Physic World* changes physics for all `SKObjects`.

Comment: if I under tend you correctly, your solution is to have different value for `gravity`and `speed` for iPad and iPhone ? What about approach to set `mass` of object ?